# RelativeLayout, align a view at the bottom of another view but always below another

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am going mad with a layout problem, based on the following image
[image: Layout problem]

The image represents a RelativeLayout. I need the blue view to be aligned with the bottom of the black one. BUT, if the black view is shorter than the sum of the red one and the blue one, I need the blue view to be below the red one. I want to have this result:

[image: Right result]

I tried with the following xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/blackView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:align_parentTop="true"
        android:align_parentLeft="true"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/redView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:align_parentTop="true"
        android:align_parentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blackView"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/blueView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/blackView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/redView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but it seems that the layout_alignBottom has a higher priority over the layout_below.
I also tried to set the blueView aligned with the bottom of its parent but the result is that the parent (having a `wrap_content` height) become high as its own parent (the whole screen height).

Does anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Please, post full layout XML.

Comment: Posted the useful part of the xml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/blackView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/redView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/blueView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#003CFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/blackView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/redView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom|right" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/blueView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The trick is that `android:gravity="bottom|right"`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/blackView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/redView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="#FF0000" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/blueView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="#003CFF" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The problem here is that the container (the LinearLayout) has a fixed height. But I need to have a wrap_content there, because under that view there are other views.

Comment: @Massimo you can use `android:layout_height="0dp"` `weight` for container (the LinearLayout) like 0.4 and remaining view `weight` 0.6

Answer (score 0):

I can solve it by using a zero size view to mark position:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<View
    android:id="@+id/blackView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:align_parentTop="true"
    android:align_parentLeft="true"/>
<View 
    android:id="@+id/blackViewBotom"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/blackView"/>
<View
    android:id="@+id/redView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:align_parentTop="true"
    android:align_parentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blackView"/>
<View
    android:id="@+id/blueView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/blackView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/redView"
    android:layout_above="@id/blackViewBotom"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

Relative Layout:
Just add **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"**
**No need of** android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle" attribute for this bottom view.